# How do I combine a left join with a like in Sybase SQL?

Tags: sql, left-join, sap-ase, sql-like

I am stuck trying to combine a `like` with a *left join* in Sybase.

For example (although in my case it's a bit more complicated), I am looking for text that neither contains an `o` nor an `i`.

I am able to do the opposite, that is, text containing either of these letters:

```
select numbers.name from 
(
      select 'one'   name union all
      select 'two'   name union all
      select 'three' name union all -- neither %o% nor %i%
      select 'four'  name union all
      select 'five'  name union all
      select 'six'   name union all
      select 'seven' name union all -- neither %o% nor %i%
      select 'eight' name union all
      select 'nine'  name union all
      select 'ten'   name           -- neither %o% nor %i%
) numbers,
(
      select '%o%'  expression union all
      select '%i%'  expression       
) patterns
where
  numbers.name like patterns.expression
```

selects all records except `three`, `seven` and `ten` as expected.

Now, I am looking for a way to find these three records. I thought about left joining *numbers* with *patterns* and then filtering on the expression being null. Something like this:

```
numbers.name *like patterns.expression and
patterns.expression is null
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. So, I'd be happy for any pointer given into the right direction.

For what's its worth, this is the version I am working on:

```
select @@version
'Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3/EBF 17156 ESD#3/P/Sun_svr4/OS 5.8/ase1503/2726/64-bit/FBO/Fri Feb  5 05:26:23 2010'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `NOT EXISTS` (it's the case):

```
select numbers.name from 
(
      select 'one'   name union all
      select 'two'   name union all
      select 'three' name union all -- neither %o% nor %i%
      select 'four'  name union all
      select 'five'  name union all
      select 'six'   name union all
      select 'seven' name union all -- neither %o% nor %i%
      select 'eight' name union all
      select 'nine'  name union all
      select 'ten'   name           -- neither %o% nor %i%
) numbers
where not exists (select null
                    from (
                             select '%o%'  expression union all
                             select '%i%'  expression
                         ) patterns
                   where numbers.name like patterns.expression)
```